# Eventhandler: Sender-cast vs. reflection

Tags: c#, reflection, casting

I have a probably simple issue but my knowledge doesn't cover up why I got a different behavior with the following code:

```
private void Test_ResultStateChangedEventHandler(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    Testcases.AbstractTestCase tc = (Testcases.AbstractTestCase)sender;

    System.Reflection.MethodInfo mInfo = sender.GetType().BaseType.GetMethod("get_TestResult");

    object retval = mInfo.Invoke(sender, new object[] { });

    if (retval != tc.TestResult) 
        throw new ArgumentException(); // Just to get a hold
}
```

I got the abstract base class *AbstractTestCase* where the property *TestResult* is beeing changed while runtime.

The initial value is "Undefined" whose change should not raise the ResultStateChangedEventHandler. This is ok so far.

If I change the result state then I expect it to be "not_tested". Immediately after the test start (which follows directly after the initialize that sets the value to "not_tested") this property is set to "running" causing the event to fire.

Now I got two different results depending on whether I access this abstact class via reflection or if I simpyl cast my sender to my *AbstractTestCase* class type.

While reflection delivers "not_tested" as expected, the direct cast will deliver "running" even though the single step with the debugger is also saying "not_tested".

It's to mention, that the testcase is running in a different thread and therefore I suppose that the value has already been changed before I access it's property.

The reason this confuses me, is because I expected reflection as beeing way more slow than a instance reference that I create by casting the sender to my *tc*-variable.

I'd prefer to use the cast instead of the reflection because it's a whole bunch of code to simply access the class members.

So where's my mistake? And if reflection is slower, why is my cast even slower than the slow reflection? Thank you :)

## Edit 1: Some more code

*_tcMngr* is nothing more than a collection of classes allowing to dynamically run the different testcases and is fed with the dummy class. Eventhandler and the code below is running in UI Thread. *AbstractTestCase* is running in a new thread.

In the UI thread there's beeing started the test:

```
_tcMngr.Initialize(identifier);

var t = Task.Factory.StartNew(() =>
{
    _tcMngr.RunSingle(identifier);
});
```

This is the property that is set while running:

```
public abstract class AbstractTestCase : TestReport, IStdTestCase
{
    public delegate void StatusChangedEventHandler(object sender, StatusChangedEventArgs e);

    public event StatusChangedEventHandler StatusChanged;

    protected virtual void OnStatusChanged(StatusChangedEventArgs e)
    {
        if (StatusChanged != null)
            StatusChanged(this, e);
    }

    protected virtual void ReportProgress(int percentage, string step, int maxPercentage = 100)
    {
        OnStatusChanged(new StatusChangedEventArgs()
        {
            Percentage = percentage,
            Step = step,
            MaxPercentage = maxPercentage               
        });
    }

    public class StatusChangedEventArgs : EventArgs
    {
        public int Percentage { get; set; } = 0;
        public int MaxPercentage { get; set; } = 100;
        public string Step { get; set; } = "";
    }

    public abstract void Run();
    public abstract void Dispose();
    public abstract string ShortDescription {
        get;
    }

    public virtual int EstimatedRuntime { get; } = 100;

    public abstract override string ToString();
    public abstract void Initialize();

    public int Identifier { get; set; }
}

public abstract class TestReport {
    public enum TestCaseResultStates
    {
        Running = 2,
        Success = 1,
        Fail = 0,
        Undefined = -1,
        NotTested = int.MaxValue
    }


    TestCaseResultStates _testresult = TestCaseResultStates.Undefined;

    public TestCaseResultStates TestResult
    {
        get
        {
            return _testresult;
        }

        set
        {
            _testresult = value;

            OnResultStateChanged(null);
        }
    }
}
```

And this is a dummy test case for debugging:

```
public class Dummy : AbstractTestCase
{
    public override string ShortDescription
    {
        get
        {
            return "Dummy for debugging.";
        }
    }

    public override void Dispose()
    {
        // nothing to do here
    }

    public override void Initialize()
    {
        base.TestResult = TestCaseResultStates.NotTested;
    }

    public override void Run()
    {
        base.TestResult = TestCaseResultStates.Running;

        for (int i = 1; i < 11; i++)
        {
            System.Threading.Thread.Sleep(1000);

            base.ReportProgress(i * 10, "Step " + i + " / 10");
        }

        base.TestResult = TestCaseResultStates.Fail;
        base.TextResult = "Test was finished: \"" + base.TestResult.ToString() + "\"";
    }

    public override string ToString()
    {
        return "Dummy";
    }

    public override int EstimatedRuntime
    {
        get
        {
            return 10;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: So you have two different threads: one that is performing something with `testcase` (and presumably changing its state) and another one on which the event is invoked?

Comment: Smells like a threading race.  Or some weird consequence of not using Type.GetProperty().  When you don't show us what the property looks like then it is just blind guessing, no point to that.

Comment: Hmm.. I'll try to add some more relevant code but there honestly there isn't so much more.

Comment: Use the debugger.  Set a breakpoint on the TestResult property setter, the stack trace tells you what code changed its value.

Comment: Well, I do change the value (and it should be changed). This value change will raise the event and there I expect reflection to be slower than a direct type cast. I wonder why it isn't the exact opposite way? However, as mentioned this race condition might become a problem and therefore I got to do some changed on my code anyways.

Comment: I suppose I got it. Before accessing the (MethodInvoker) the event is still in the caller-thread and first with entering the anonymous method it's switching to the ui thread. Therefore the debugger say it's still "not_tested" because the caller thread is beeing stopped until the event has been handled completely. As soon as the delegate function is beeing calles the caller thread continues switching the not_tested to running. The reason why the invokation via reflection delivers the old value is not because it's faster, but it's creating a copy and not a reference. That's why reflection works.